# xml+xslt not rendering properly in IE 9

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I just wrote an xml file (Order.xml) and want to render it using xsl (order.xsl).When I try to launch the Order.xml in IE 9 it just displays plain text without any styling.

But for a xml file copied (food.xml) from web (which is used for demo purpose) works well with proper styling as specified in xsl (food1.xsl) file.

**Order.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="order.xsl"?>
<PRODUCTDATA>
    <PRODUCT PRODID="001">
        <PRODUCTNAME>Barbie Doll</PRODUCTNAME>
             <DESCRIPTION>This is a toy for children in the age group of                 5-10 years</DESCRIPTION>
        <PRICE>$20.00</PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>12</QUANTITY>
    </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTDATA>
```

**order.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="PRODUCTDATA/PRODUCT"">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="PRODUCTNAME"/></span>
         <xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
        <span style="font-style:italic">
          <xsl:value-of select="QUANTITY"/> 
        </span>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

**food.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpyÂ® -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="food1.xsl"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>French Toast</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

**food1.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpyÂ® -->
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>
        - <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        <span style="font-style:italic">
          <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving)
        </span>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio says you have an excessive `"` in `select="PRODUCTDATA/PRODUCT"">`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra double quote on this line in your `order.xsl`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="PRODUCTDATA/PRODUCT"">
```

Comment: I just got the below output without any styling _Barbie Doll This is a toy for children in the age group of 5-10 years $20.00 12_